# Adding base64 encoded icons to a SPFx ListView CommandSet Extension

Tags: base64, spfx

I'm trying to add an icon to the ListView CommandSet Extension I created using Waldek's tutorial [Configure extension icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/basics/configure-extension-icon#extension-types-that-support-icons).

The issue I have is:
Getting a gulp warning `*appears to be a relative web URL. This means that when the is rendered, this URL will be relative to the CDN url for the rest of the package assets. If a relative filesystem path was intended, prepend the path with "./".*` and not showing an icon in the commandset.

It's trying to open https://localhost:4321/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0...

I'm working on the newest SPFx version 1.4.0 using a React framework.

This is the extension manifest.

```
"items": {
"COMMAND_1": {
  "title": {
    "default": "<command title>"
  },
  "iconImageUrl": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABGdBTUEAALGLDJGlHAAAACBjSFJNAACHCwAAjA8AAP1SAACBQgAAfXUAAOmPAAA85gAAGc0Hn9XQAAAg1GlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAaN6VkWVUlklFTkSuQmCC..<removed chunk>",
  "type": "command"
}
```

}

Please give some advise or pointers to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a known issue from Microsoft's end.

Would suggest that you wait a couple of days for it to be resolved. If its a blocking issue, would suggest that you use an image(with file url) and that which is accessible to all users.

Github issue - [Web part Base 64 icons do not render anymore](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1124)

Comment: I though I searched thoroughly, but I still missed the issue. Thank you for the link.

Comment: happy to help, cheers :) , could you please accept it as answer by checking the checkmark. You can view how to do it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score -1):

Erik,

I also had the same issue so I dug into it and found a way to use SVG with custom icons.

I posted a blog about it (https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/08/31/fixing-base64-svg-icons-in-spfx/), but the solution is to **not** use base64-encoding, just use the html-encoded SVG in the data url.

I hope this helps?